# On Etherscan, what is the difference between a failed transaction that says 'Reverted' and one that says 'Execution Reverted'?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, rinkeby, revert-opcode, goerli

On Etherscan, a failed transaction will provide a reason for failure. This can be [`Reverted`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6ea1798a2d0d21db18d6e45ca00f230160b05f172f6022aa138a0b605831d740), [`Out of Gas`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5871434b2e89ac62d643cc42a6c44ba75e16f229dbbdba3994e8202df5f1102f), [`Bad instruction`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb84a441996ba3cffc82b17c5dd282b02feeb63826846931a8d16211fbece45bf), etc.

However, there seems to be an inconsistent message on different testnets. I deployed this contract on all the networks:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract FailedFallback {

    function () external payable {
        require(1==2, "Failed test");
    }
}
```

When calling the fallback function on Rinkeby, Etherscan says [`execution reverted`](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x05df68d63b38630f2b07276778fd211450afdc8c254372d6bd14a5c9c3adcf5b), however any other network simply says [`Reverted`](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x16da17eeeb24752aa29ae81d6097736b19f7fee3b367281b63081f98c5abb17a).

Is this an inconsistency with Etherscan or the the VM of the network? At the VM level, are these reversions the exact same? Does this have something to do with a Geth vs. Parity trace?

Comment: Looks like somebody on Etherscan has missed the advantages of code-reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an inconsistency of the different client implementations.

go-ethereum (geth) uses the string `execution reverted` ([source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/8dc89415511ec0d5f8b0128e9ef9fb624ddb5d56/core/vm/instructions.go#L35))

OpenEthereum (fomerly parity) uses the string `Reverted` ([source](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/blob/3ccfe735aa579f89a1f8de192a7625084a6f530f/ethcore/vm/src/error.rs#L114))

The revert error message is returned when execution has been reverted with the `REVERT` opcode, so they are the exact same.